# Call to open(2) ignores S_IWGRP and S_IWOTH flags

Tags: c, debian

`S_IWGRP` and `S_IWOTH` flags does not make any effect when specified in `open(2)`.

File opened and created as

```
open(file,O_CREAT|O_WRONLY,S_IWGRP|S_IWOTH);
```

that resulting in

```
---------- 1 root root 0 Jul 16 21:25 file
```

any other flags works properly.

Where should I start the troubleshooting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider the processes `umask` value. See `man 2 umask`.

The umask value is subtracted from the permission mask given to `open(2)`. That is, if you do `open(file,O_CREAT|O_WRONLY,mymask)` then then actual mask is *not* `mymask` but `mymask & ~umask`.

Most users start with a umask value of `022` [octal], which is `S_IWGRP | S_IWOTH`.

A user's umask value can be controlled by the shell builtin command `umask`.

A process may change the umask value via the `umask(2)` syscall. In your case, try:

```
oldval = umask(0);
open(...);
umask(oldval);
```

Note: This works fine in a single threaded environment, but extra steps should be taken with a multithreaded program.

Another way is to use `fchmod`:

```
fd = open(...);
fchmod(fd,mymask);
```

This is probably safer for multithread, but if the program aborts between the `open` but before the `fchmod`, you'll end up with the same situation as you have (e.g. zero mask). So, a `<CTRL-C>`, system crash, etc. that is well timed can produce this.

---

**UPDATE:**

> I'm confused about it because when I'm printing the real value of S_IRWXU flag I get an 442. Why it is not just a number 7

I'm not completely sure, because I don't know if `442` was decimal or octal, but I'll try to cover all the bases [pun intended :-)].

The layout of a permissions mask, which is normally printed in *octal* [`"%o"` format] is:

```
owner(3) | group(3) | other(3)
```

That is, each is 3 bits wide

The `S_IRWXU` define is a fixed define for "all *owner* permissions". It has an octal value of `700` which is `448` decimal. So, *if* you were doing `printf("%d\n",S_IRWXU)` I would expect the `448`

`printf("%d\n",mask & S_IRWXU)` [or even `printf("%d\n",mask & S_IRWXU)`] can *not* produce `442` because *that* decimal value is octal `672`. The `672` would get masked down to `600` octal or `384` decimal. But, this is *not* possible.

So, if the decimal value were *really* `448` and *not* `442`, this yields `700` octal which means "owner has all permissions"

So, the only way that things make sense to me is that the `442` was the octal value for the *entire* permissions mask [and was masked against `777` octal].

To clarify, here is a file snippet of `stat.h` that defines the various values [the comments were added by me]:

```
#define S_IRWXU 00700       // mask for owner
#define S_IRUSR 00400       // owner may read
#define S_IWUSR 00200       // owner may write
#define S_IXUSR 00100       // owner may execute

#define S_IRWXG 00070       // mask for group
#define S_IRGRP 00040       // group may read
#define S_IWGRP 00020       // group may write
#define S_IXGRP 00010       // group may execute

#define S_IRWXO 00007       // mask for others
#define S_IROTH 00004       // others may read
#define S_IWOTH 00002       // others may write
#define S_IXOTH 00001       // others may execute
```

So, `442` is `r|r|w` which say owner and group can read and others can write [but *not* read]. This wouldn't make much sense for a given *file*, so this implies the mask in question is the `umask` value. But, even then, this still doesn't make much sense because, as a `umask` value, *removing* read permission for the owner isn't the usual thing to do.

Notice that `S_IRWXU` is `00700`, so if you right shift that by 6, you *do* get `7`. Likewise, `S_IRWXG` is `00070`, so if right shift that by 3, you also get `7`

More likely, the value you want to mask against is `S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO` [group/others] because that is what you were trying to override in your original question.

If you're still having trouble, and can clarify a bit more what you're doing to get the value, I may be able to revise this further to help.

Comment: Definitely the correct direction! Can you suggest how can I understand the calculation algorithm? I'm confused about it because when I'm printing the real value of S_IRWXU flag I get an 442. Why it is not just a number 7?

Answer (score 1):

When any file is created, its permission bits are masked by the complement of the current `umask`. So if `umask` has been set to `022` (a typical value), permissions will be masked (bitwise-anded) by `0755`.

If you really need files to atomically have group/world write permissions at the moment they're created, you can call `umask(0)`, but this is generally bad practice because the setting is process-global and might cause unsafe file creation elsewhere (or in your child processes). A better approach, if it works, is just to call `fchmod` after opening the file to add the permissions that were masked off.